# How to know how many MB has my Intel graphic card?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

I had Windows 10 installed, and I could see that I have Intel HD Graphics 4000 with almost 2GB of video, but on Ubuntu I can't find that info.
Using hardinfo on Ubuntu, I see VGA Memory 256MB.
How to update or download the appropriate graphic drivers?

Comment: The title and the question in the body of your post are in fact different. What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @edwinksl, I want to know both things: the graphic card installed on my pc and the MB that it has.